# Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject exception when add multiple criteria GridFSDBFile query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want add multiple criteria in GridFSDBFile, I have iterated the map and formed the criteria object but i am getting following exception

> Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a
>   second '$and' expression specified.

My code snippet is

```
public void getFile(Map<String, Object> metaData) throws Exception {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    metaData.forEach((k, v) -> criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("metadata." + k).is(v)));
    GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridFsOperations.findOne(new Query(criteria));
    if (gridFSDBFile == null) {
        throw new HttpConflictException();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can update method to below. You are trying to provide multiple `$and` operator with each having a criteria.

Btw, you don't need an explicit `and`ing as mongodb provides implicit `and`ing when criteria is separated by comma.

```
public void getFile(Map<String, Object> metaData) throws Exception {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    metaData.forEach((k, v) -> criteria.and("metadata." + k).is(v));
    GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridFsOperations.findOne(new Query(criteria));
    if (gridFSDBFile == null) {
        throw new HttpConflictException();
}
```

In cases where you need explicit `and`ing, you can use below code

```
public void getFile(Map<String, Object> metaData) throws Exception {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    Criteria[] andExpressions = metaData.entrySet().stream().
            map(kv -> Criteria.where("data." + kv.getKey()).is(kv.getValue()))
            .toArray(Criteria[]::new);
    Query andQuery = new Query();
    Criteria andCriteria = new Criteria();
    andQuery.addCriteria(andCriteria.andOperator(andExpressions));
    GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridFsOperations.findOne(andQuery);
    if (gridFSDBFile == null) {
        throw new HttpConflictException();
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that this works. I've tried something extremely similar, and I have no idea why it didn't work. Sadly it was a few days ago and I can't be asked to check my local history.  Point is, you need an array of Criteria[] `Criteria.where(X).is(Y)`. A query, a new root empty criteria `Criteria root = new Criteria`, then `query.addCriteria(root.andOperator(criteriaArray))` and it works. So I would change the above code by replacing `collect(toList())` with `toArray(Criteria[]::new)` and no more `toArray` later on. Either way, great answer!