# MongoTemplate how to add more than two "orOperator" in Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to execute a request in MongoDB which contains 4 logical "or" at once, I mean something like ((a == null || a == 0) || (b == null || b == 0))

I'm trying to execute this request but catch an exception `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'null' criteria. Query already contains '{ "$or" : [{ "a" : null}, { "a" : 0.0}]}'`

There is my code:

```
    Criteria aCriteria = new Criteria();
    aCriteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("a").is(null), Criteria.where("a").is(0.0d));
    Criteria bCriteria = new Criteria();
    bCriteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("b").is(null), Criteria.where("b").is(0.0d));

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(aCriteria);
    query.addCriteria(bCriteria);
    List<POJO> arbitrages = mongoTemplate.find(query, POJO.class, "DB");
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject exception when add multiple criteria GridFSDBFile query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907333/due-to-limitations-of-the-com-mongodb-basicdbobject-exception-when-add-multiple)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following query `Criteria` will work using the `orOperator`:

```
Criteria c = new Criteria().orOperator(
                              Criteria.where("a").is(0),
                              Criteria.where("a").is(null),
                              Criteria.where("b").is(0),
                              Criteria.where("b").is(null)
);

Query query = new Query(c);
List<POJO> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, POJO.class, "DB");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had really complex MongoDb query with lot of `$or`, `$and` and `null` conditions. Because of large number of queried fields I was not in position to do something as @prasad proposed. Instead of it I was using different level for of nesting for each part of criteria. I used:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criteria, secondCriteria);
criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criteria, thirdCriteria);
...
```