# Spring Data MongoDB - Add multiple keys to the same field in Criteria

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, criteria-api

I want to add multiple keys in the criteria with the same field name. I have iterated the key values, however, I got the following error.

```
    // names= ["abc", "def"];  
    // fieldName = "customerName"; 
    // the statement would be where boughtId=pizza0 and name=abc or name=def
private Criteria createCriteria(List<String> names, String fieldName) {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("boughtId").is("pizza0");
    for (String name: names) {
      criteria.and(fieldName).is(name);
    }
    return criteria; 
}
```

Error:

> "Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a
> second 'customerName' expression specified as 'customerName: def'.
> Criteria already contains 'customerName: abc'."

Comment: So only add unique criteria.  The error is suggesting you have duplicate criteria speceified. The example above shows a criteria for field 'boughtId' = 'pizza0'.  If you include a second criteria for the same field 'boughtId' = 'pizza1' you will get this error.

Comment: If you need to filter for multiple values on a single field use the $in operator instead of $eq.  For Spring Data I believe you replace the .is() method with .in(), then add the multiple criteria for the single field as a comma separated list of strings, or perhaps an array - I can't recall - I would need to defer to the documentation for the syntax.

Comment: Here is a SO post showing usage of a same field with _or_ operator (a `MongoTemplate` query): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447700/mongotemplate-how-to-add-more-than-two-oroperator-in-query/62448420#62448420